# Where to get a copy of: Valeurs principales associées aux temps locaux Browniens

Tags: reference-request

All:

Where to get a copy of an paper: Valeurs principales associées aux temps locaux Browniens

The paper was published on: Bulletin des Sciences Mathématiques
Bull. Sci. Math. 111 (1987), p. 23-101

Our library does not have this journal for 1987.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: You could ask the author, through 
 https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/2029220171_Ph_Biane , or directly through http://monge.univ-mlv.fr/~biane/ .

Comment: Have you asked your librarian whether it is possible to get it via interlibrary loan?

Comment: https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Valeurs-principales-associ%C3%A9es-aux-temps-locaux-Biane-Yor/de72ed58e4e641b7b9b9ad11979b578e673a747c

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, that link is not downloadable.

Comment: I know but your librarian could get it.

Comment: http://monge.univ-mlv.fr/~biane/ contains  Philippe Biane's e-mail address. Just contact him. If you cannot, I even could ring him. He coauthored the paper

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thank you, I will try.

Comment: I already contacted Prof. Biane (may be easier from Prof to Prof !). If he reacts, I should let you know. So, do not delete your post or contact me (my e-mail address is in my profile.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici, thank you very much !

Comment: @david. I have a scanned copy of the paper. Send me an e-mail (my address is in my profile) and I shall transfer it to you.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you. I just sent you an email. (Apologized that I had not login StackExchange for a while, so I had not seen your message till today.)

Comment: @david Is there a way you can sent me a copy of the paper? Claude has lost his copy. Just sent it to biane2023@yopmail.com and I can get it from there.

Comment: @JorgeE.Cardona, I emailed you. FYI, the scanned copies still missed two pages.